# MySQL com .Net 4.6.2 - Erro "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto." classe dbContext

Tags: c#, mysql

Caros amigos!
Estou com um problema ao tentar acesso na classe dbContext com Mysql, ao acessar o por exemplo Context.set().Add(obj), recebo a mensagem de erro "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."
o projeto é uma web api simples, onde o controller acessa o banco através de uma classe de serviço que herda de uma classe abstrata métodos para gestão de dados(classe repositoro) no banco, inferfaces com ações padrão (crud). mas mesmo assim recebo erro.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ContatoService _ContatoService;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(Contato obj)
    {
        _ContatoService = new ContatoService();
        _ContatoService.Post(obj);

    }
}

public class ContatoService : ContatoRepository, IBaseService<Contato>
{
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        if (id == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Para realizar a exclusão é necessário identificar o registro.");
        Remove(id);
    }

    public Contato Get(int id)
    {
        if (id == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Para realizar a seleção da informação é necessário identificar o registro.");
        return Select(id);
    }

    public List<Contato> Get()
    {
        return SelectAll();
    }

    public Contato Post(Contato obj)
    {
        return Insert(obj);
    }

    public Contato Put(Contato obj)
    {
        return Update(obj);

    }
}

public interface IBaseService<T>
{
    T Post(T obj);
    T Put(T obj);
    void Delete(int id);
    T Get(int id);
    List<T> Get();
}

public class ContatoRepository: BaseRepository<Contato>
{
}

public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IDisposable, IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    MySQLContext _Context = new MySQLContext();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Context.Dispose();
    }

    public T Insert(T obj)
    {
        //-- O erro acontece ao acessar _Context...
        _Context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
        return obj;
    }

    public void Remove(int id)
    {
        if (id == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Para realizar essa ação, é necessário informar um identificador.");
        _Context.Set<T>().Remove(Select(id));
    }

    public T Select(int id)
    {
        if (id == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Para realizar essa ação, é necessário informar um identificador.");
        return _Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public List<T> SelectAll()
    {
        return _Context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public T Update(T obj)
    {
        _Context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        return obj;
    }
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T Insert(T obj);
    T Update(T obj);
    void Remove(int id);
    T Select(int id);
    List<T> SelectAll();

}

    public class MySQLContext: DbContext
{
    public MySQLContext(): base("MySQLConString") {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
    {
        modelbuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelbuilder.Entity<Contato>().ToTable("site_contato");
    }

    public DbSet<Contato> Contato { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: e "MySQLConString" está definido no arquivo de configuração? a string está correta?

Comment: Bom dia meu amigo @RicardoPontual, sim está definida no meu web.config, e está correta, pois eu a uso em um projeto .net Core.

Answer (score 0):

Luciano, não sei se é o seu caso mas já foi o meu, no caso recebia esta mesma mensagem quando precisava inserir um objeto composto por outros objetos. No meu caso as propriedades do objeto principal estavam ok, no entanto um dado de um dos objetos que compunham o objeto principal, tinha uma das propriedades inválida.

Se possível posta a sua classe Contato. E caso ela possua algum objeto como propriedade, adiciona ele na sua classe de contexto.

Espero ter ajudado.